# Remove from superview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Just a small question i'm really having a lot of problems with

Basically, what I'm doing is making a view every time I hit a button which works fine.
When I want to remove all the images I made when I hit the remove from superview it just removes the last one on the stack.
Is there a way i can get rid of all the images I made?

Here is the code

This puts the picture on the screen

```
- (IBAction)pushBn:(id)sender {


    ZeldaView *newZelda = [[ZeldaView alloc]initWithNibName:@"ZeldaView" bundle:nil];

    theZeldaView=newZelda;
    [self.view insertSubview:theZeldaView.view atIndex:1];

}
```

this removes it when i touch it

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{


    UITouch *touch =[touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location=[touch locationInView:theZeldaView.view];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(theZeldaView.theImage.frame, location)) {

        [theZeldaView.view removeFromSuperview];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just iterate through the children of your parent view (self.view) and remove any that are ZeldaView elements.

At it's simplest this would be something like:

```
for (UIView* subView in [self.view.subviews])
{
    if ([subView isKindOfClass:[ZeldaView class]])
        [subView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Though you will probably want to expand on this to not perform the actual removal during the iteration and you may want to use respondsToSelector and a custom method instead of checking the class here so that you can do any cleanup needed from within the ZeldaView class. Hopefully that makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

sure, many ways to do this. I would keep an array of `ZeldaView` objects and when you want to remove them, traverse the array and remove them all.

in your .h:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *zeldaViews;
```

when you add a ZeldaView:

```
// create a newZeldaView and add it to the superview
[self.zeldaViews addObject:newZeldaView];
```

when you want to remove them all:

```
for (ZeldaView *zeldaView in self.zeldaViews) {
    [zeldaView.view removeFromSuperview];
}
[self.zeldaViews removeAllObjects];
```

create the mutable array in viewDidLoad and release it in viewDidUnload and dealloc. Modify as approp if your using ARC.

Comment: for some reason it is still not removing the view

Comment: if you copied my code verbatim, I had a mistake. I didn't notice that `zeldaView` is a controller b/c of the naming. based on your original code, you need to remove the views in the loop with `[zeldaView.view removeFromSuperview]`. Aside from that, you'd have to post your new code.

Comment: in any case, if you are putting the views that you add to the main view in the array and then removing them from the superview by iterating through the array this will work. it it's not, then you have something else wrong in your code.

Comment: Logically that makes the most sence but for some reason I'm having trouble implementing it
So I made a work around
This is what I did
I made a new view controller to create the imageview in every time I hit my button I create another picture
Then just removed that one view controller from superview

Comment: your app implementation is suspect. generally you don't create a new controller just to add a view to a superview. for example, you don't create a UIButtonController to add a UIButton. It sounds to me like ZeldaView should be a subclass of UIView (not UIViewController) and the controller logic should be in the controller that you are adding the subviews to. That would be the most common design pattern.

Comment: I changed it to what you said but removing that view from superview also thank for your help